# Is there a way to change the default country of the PayPal credit card form?

Tags: paypal

I'm integrating PayPal into my website, using these settings.

```
    paypal.Buttons({
        locale: "en_GB",
        style: {
            color:  'blue',
            shape:  'pill',
            label:  'pay',
            height: 40
        },
```

If you use PayPal all is well and it shows up in GBP, but if you decide to pay using a credit card it always seems to default to US. I can't find anything on the PayPal developer website, nor here. Is there any way to change this?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Setting the "buyer-country" in the script tag line, did not work for me.
Neither did setting it as an item in the paypal.Buttons ({ script code.
Clicking the Credit Card button always defaulted to US.

What did work is setting the "locale".

For example

```
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?locale=en_AU&currency=AUD&client-id=*SB_CLIENT_ID*"></script>
```

This is in sandbox mode.

Comment: Works in live mode too.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you - also, thank you!

Comment: Hey ! I am having the exact same issue as yours. Where do I need to place this code for it to work ? I am a complete noob regarding code and WP. For USA it would be: <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?locale=en_US&currency=USD&client-id=*SB_CLIENT_ID*"></script>  right ?

Comment: It defaults to en_US and USD, in the experience of others and me, so you would not need the locale and currency arguments in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the buyer's billing address, you can pass it. [Documentation here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/standard-card-fields/).

---

When testing in sandbox, you can [set "buyer-country"](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#buyer-country) in the script tag line that loads the PayPal JS. But this only applies to sandbox testing -- for live, the buyer country will be auto detected.